# Cannot `. tz_localize()` to an European Time Zone

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a `date_range`:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start="2022-01-01", end='2022-06-25', freq="30min")
```

I want to set a **Time Zone** following the instructions of this [tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html):

```
dates.tz_localize('Europe/Warsaw')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NonExistentTimeError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/24/tg28vxls25l9mjvqrnh0plc80000gn/T/ipykernel_39654/1790666542.py in <module>
----> 1 dates.tz_localize('Europe/Warsaw')

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in tz_localize(self, tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
    277     @doc(DatetimeArray.tz_localize)
    278     def tz_localize(self, tz, ambiguous="raise", nonexistent="raise") -> DatetimeIndex:
--> 279         arr = self._data.tz_localize(tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
    280         return type(self)._simple_new(arr, name=self.name)
    281 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/_mixins.py in method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     56     def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
     57         if self.ndim == 1:
---> 58             return meth(self, *args, **kwargs)
     59 
     60         flags = self._ndarray.flags

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in tz_localize(self, tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
   1022             # Convert to UTC
   1023 
-> 1024             new_dates = tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc(
   1025                 self.asi8, tz, ambiguous=ambiguous, nonexistent=nonexistent
   1026             )

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/tslibs/tzconversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc()

NonExistentTimeError: 2022-03-27 02:00:00
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From provided link
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html

> **nonexistentstr, default ‘raise’** A nonexistent time does not exist in a particular timezone where clocks moved forward due to DST. Valid
> values are:
>
> - ‘shift_forward’ will shift the nonexistent time forward to the closest existing time
> - ‘shift_backward’ will shift the nonexistent time backward to the closest existing time
> - ‘NaT’ will return NaT where there are nonexistent times
> - timedelta objects will shift nonexistent times by the timedelta ‘raise’ will raise an NonExistentTimeError if there are nonexistent
>   times.

So, your code will work with such params:

- nonexistent='shift_forward'
- nonexistent='shift_backward'
- nonexistent='NaT'

e t.c. as written in the documentation

```py
dates = pd.date_range(start="2022-01-01", end='2022-06-25', freq="30min")
dates.tz_localize('Europe/Warsaw',nonexistent='NaT')
```